# How to have a separate color for each face on my object in OpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, colors

Total OpenGL noob here... I am trying to color each face of a pyramid in a different color like so:

```
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    f1 = ((1,-1,-1),(1,-1,1),(0,1,0))
    f2 = ((1,-1,1),(-1,-1,1),(0,1,0))
    f3 = ((-1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,1),(0,1,0))
    f4 = ((1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,-1),(0,1,0))
    f5 = ((1,-1,-1),(1,-1,1),(-1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,1))
    for i in f1:
        glColor3f(0,255,255)
        glVertex3fv(i)
    for i in f2:
        glColor3f(255,0,0)
        glVertex3fv(i)
    for i in f3:
        glColor3f(0,255,0)
        glVertex3fv(i)
    for i in f4:
        glColor3f(255,255,0)
        glVertex3fv(i)
    for i in f5:
        glColor3f(255,0,255)
        glVertex3fv(i)
    glEnd()
```

but the result is awful... what am i doing wrong?
[My current pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW33L.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primitive type `GL_POLYGON` makes 1 large polygon out of all vertices in the `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequence. Note that OpenGL cannot guess how many points make up a single polygon. You need to draw the polygons in separated `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences:

```py
faces = [
    ((1,-1,-1),(1,-1,1),(0,1,0)),
    ((1,-1,1),(-1,-1,1),(0,1,0)),
    ((-1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,1),(0,1,0)),
    ((1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,-1),(0,1,0)),
    ((1,-1,-1),(1,-1,1),(-1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,1))
]
colors = [(0,255,255), (255,0,0), (0,255,0), (255,255,0), (255,0,255)]

for face, color in zip(faces, colors):
    glColor3fv(color)
    
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    for vertex in face:
        glVertex3fv(vertex)
    glEnd()
```

---

Alternatively, you can draw `GL_TRIANGLES` and make the bottom of the pyramid by 2 triangles:

```py
tringles = [
    ((1,-1,-1),   (1,-1,1),   (0,1,0)),
    ((1,-1,1),   (-1,-1,1),  (0,1,0)),
    ((-1,-1,-1), (-1,-1,1),  (0,1,0)),
    ((1,-1,-1),  (-1,-1,-1), (0,1,0)),
    ((1,-1,-1),  (1,-1,1),   (-1,-1,-1)),
    ((1,-1,-1),  (-1,-1,-1), (-1,-1,1))
]
colors = [
    (0,255,255), (255,0,0), (0,255,0), (255,255,0), 
    (255,0,255), (255,0,255)
]

glBegin(GL_TRINAGLES)
for tringle, color in zip(tringles, colors):
    glColor3fv(color)
    for vertex in triangle:
        glVertex3fv(vertex)
glEnd()
```

Comment: Well, or just change the primitive type to GL_TRIANGLES and make the base two triangles.

Comment: If you were using programmable pipeline it would just be a matter of passing color attribute per face in the vertex buffer.

Comment: @MichaelIV What are you trying to tell me? In my answer there is one color attribute per face.